# What VS extension/setting do I have to turn on to get this feature?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

What Visual Studio 2010 extension or setting turns on the feature pictured below? It allows me to jump to the matching brace and for conditional statements, it gives me a peek of the condition at the closing brace.

[image: VS Extension that allows jumping to matching brace]

Comment: Looks a bit like [code rush](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/) or one of the other dev express products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[VSCommands for Visual Studio 2010](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d491911d-97f3-4cf6-87b0-6a2882120acf) has feature called [Code Block End Tagger](http://vscommands.squaredinfinity.com/Features2010)